# How do I get the value from (php encoded json) using angular javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

In the console I can only see succes and $scope.data.username prints nothing. And a second question: In my php do i need to send status and status_massage? why?

in my js:

```
 $scope.register = function register() {
            $http.post('.../api/user.php', {username: $scope.user.username, password: $scope.user.password, func: 'register'}).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('succes');
                $scope.data = data;
                console.log($scope.data.username);
            }).
                    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('error');
            });
        };
```

In postman it wil return

```
    {
    "status": 200,
    "status_message": "OK",
    "data": {
        "username": "smith99"
    }
}
```

And my php script does:

```
            $response['status'] = 200;
        $response['status_message'] = "OK";
        $response['data'] = array(
            'username' => $user
        );    
        $jsonResponse = json_encode($response);
        echo $jsonResponse;
```

Comment: Try `$scope.data = data.data;`.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you've merged `status`,`status_message` and `data` into your response body, which is regarded as `data` in Angular's `success(function(data, status, headers, config) {})`. So a quick and dirty fix is use `$scope.data = data.data` in your success callback.

However, it's not a proper way to merge everything into the response body. For [HTTP response code](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.http-response-code.php), you should set as

```
<?php
http_response_code(200);
?>
```

while for your response body, you can simply set `username` as

```
$response['username'] = @user   
$jsonResponse = json_encode($response);
echo $jsonResponse;
```

This way you don't change your current Angular code.

Comment: the console log is now undifined and I really want to know how to read an array in json.

Comment: what's the result of `console.log(data)`

Comment: For generating array in php, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script) is helpful.